# How to implement keypresseventargs in textchanged?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I want to trigger some function in `textchanged` event if the user is pressing something,
I want to use `e.keychar` or any other key function to get user's key input inside text_changed event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TextBox's `KeyUp` event instead of `TextChanged`, and you can use `e.Key` to get user pressed keyboard key. `TextChanged` event doesn't have information about which keyboard key that trigger `TextChanged`, because user can do copy-paste text and that will trigger the event too without pressing any key. `KeyUp` is triggered after `TextChanged` event -just tested that-.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're asking for? this will return you what key are you pressing at the time?
(I really don't understand your question)

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
   if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C)) {
      MessageBox.Show("You have pressed the shortcut Ctrl+C");
      return true;
   }
   return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Microsoft Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)